# VueJS3 ref/reactive array of object keys

Tags: vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I want to watch the keys of an object, outside of a normal Vue component.

I think something like this should be possible with `reactive`, but no luck yet:

```
var myObject = {};
var keys = reactive(Object.keys(myObject));

myObject['fish'] = 200;
//keys is still []
```

Also tried:

```
var keys = reactive({keylist: Object.keys(myObject)});

var keys = ref(Object.keys(myObject));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it, it's a combination of `reactive` and the `watchEffect`. I'm still open to cleaner answers if this is anti-pattern somehow.

```
var myObject = reactive({});
var keys;
watchEffect(() => {
    keys = Object.keys(myObject);
});
```